# Common-collector output resistance and common-base input resistance

Tags: signal, input

A circuit analysis shows that the small-signal output resistance of the common-collector circuit (without consideration of the emitter resistance RE) is different from the small-signal input resistance of the common-base circuit (identical DC operating point assumed). In both cases, the test signal is applied as a voltage to the emitter terminal.

What is the clear and descriptive explanation for this (without formulas) ?

Comment: I thought it would be the same. Do you have numbers for consideration and how did you perform your analysis? Of course I'm going to ask these questions LOL.

Comment: Lack of negative feedback in the common-base amplifier because the CB capacitor kills all the feedback?

Comment: @Andyaka for CC we have ro = RB/(hfe +1) + re and for CB we gave rin = re only, isn't it?

Comment: But, if in CC you drive the base with a zero ohm AC impedance then........

Comment: .... you have ro = 0/(hFE + 1) + re = re

Answer (score 1):

Yes - as mentioned by G36 in his comment, the resulting base resistance causes **negative feedback** for any testsignal that is applied to the emitter node (in contrast to common-base).

As far as I know, this feedback effect is not mentioned in the textbooks.

This current-controlled voltage feedback increases the input resistance at the emitter node above the expected value of 1/g,e. Applying the classical feedback formula gives the expected (and well-known) expression for the input resistance r,in atthe emitter nde.

(in the drawing, "a" stands for "alpha" and "b" for "beta".)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgV0pj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: But, if the base were driven by a hard source and via a low reactance capacitor, you get the same result. There is no difference between the circuits you have analysed other than not assume a "hard base".

Comment: Andy aka, yes - you are right...in this case, Rb=0. However, in many (if not in all) cases, the common collector configuraton is used particularly when the source resistance is NOT zero (no hard drive). What is the purpose of the stage when the output of the driving stage is already near zero?

Comment: I was just trying to point out that they are the same when one factors out the CC signal source impedance.

Comment: Andy aka, OK agreed. For my opinion, and from the system theory point of view, I think it is interesting to realize (just for the purpose of understanding) that here we have another example for a hidden feedback loop ......like the negative feedback effect caused by the emiter resistor.....